# Is there a way to write this code in a 'cleaner' way? (.kv design language)

Tags: oop, kivy

There are many text inputs and buttons that need to be reset on the click of this "clear" button i made. This code i wrote does work but is there a better way to write this? Can i make a function inside a .kv file that will make this code cleaner (less repetitve)?

```
        Button:
            text: "Clear"
            font_name: font_bold
            on_press: root.clear()
            on_press: text_input_one.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_one.text = "0"
            on_press: text_input_two.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_two.text = "0"
            on_press: text_input_three.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_three.text = "0"
            on_press: text_input_four.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_four.text = "0"
            on_press: text_input_five.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_five.text = "0"
            on_press: text_input_six.background_color = root.white_color
            on_press: text_input_six.text = "0"
            on_press: bruto_button_one.state = "normal"
            on_press: neto_button_one.state = "normal"
```

I tried making a function inside the .kv file but i dont really know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code snippet and the following actually do the same work.

```py
        Button:
            text: "Clear"
            font_name: font_bold
            on_press:
                root.clear()
                text_input_one.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_one.text = "0"
                text_input_two.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_two.text = "0"
                text_input_three.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_three.text = "0"
                text_input_four.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_four.text = "0"
                text_input_five.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_five.text = "0"
                text_input_six.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_six.text = "0"
                bruto_button_one.state = "normal"
                neto_button_one.state = "normal"
```

Also perhaps you can omit the following lines and handle them in their corresponding source seperately:

```py
                text_input_one.background_color = root.white_color
                text_input_one.text = "0"
                ... etc.
```